# How to find that ScrollViewer is scrolled to the top end in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer in my view.. I have the requirement that whether scorollview is scrolled to the Top end? Is there any way?

Better if i can get solution in mvvm model..

Comment: How about making a Behavior or Attached Property that listens for the ScrollViewer::ScrollChanged event, checks the VerticalOffset and calls a method/command on your ViewModel? For example ScrollViewerHelper.ScrolledToTopCommand="{Binding ScrolledToTop}"

Comment: If you asking to make ScrollViewer scroll to top then just call the method ScrollToTop(); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltotop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am not asking about how to scroll to top..but if i scroll to top then how can i recognize that scrollviewer is scrolled to top?

Comment: @atomaras, your suggestion is the best solution for this problem... any chance that you could show the user how to do that?

Comment: I got the solution..by verifying vertical offset is zero or not

Comment: Added the proposal to an answer so you can close it. Let me know if you want more code/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a Behavior or Attached Property that listens for the ScrollViewer::ScrollChanged event, checks the VerticalOffset and calls a method/command on your ViewModel? 
For example ScrollViewerHelper.ScrolledToTopCommand="{Binding ScrolledToTop}"

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MyScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {                
                    scrollViewer.LineUp();
                    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
                        // Top end reached                
            }
            else
            {
                    scrollViewer.LineDown();
                    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
                        // Bottom end reached                
            }
        }
```